# Oracle PL/SQL: choosing the update/merge column dynamically

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, merge

I have a table with data relating to several moments in time that I have to keep updated. To save space and time, however, each row in my table refers to a given day and hourly and quarter-hourly data for that day are scattered throughout the several columns in that same row. When updating the data for a particular moment in time I, therefore, must choose the column that has to be be updated through some programming logic in my PL/SQL procedures and functions.

Is there a way to dynamically choose the column or columns involved in an update/merge operation without having to assemble the query string anew every time? Performance is a concern and the throughput must be high, so I can't do anything that would perform poorly.

Edit: I am aware of normalization issues. However I still would like to know a good way for choosing the columns to be updated/merged dynamically and programatically.

Comment: As you point out in your question you're not saving time... Have you considered normalising and can you post some table descriptions?

Comment: agreed - this sounds like a normalization issue - getting that right will make your other issues easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to dynamically choose what column or columns to use for a `DML` statement is to use dynamic SQL.  And the only way to use dynamic SQL is to generate a SQL statement that can then be prepared and executed.  Of course, you can assemble the string in a more or less efficient manner, you can potentially parse the statement once and execute it multiple times, etc. in order to minimize the expense of using dynamic SQL.  But using dynamic SQL that performs close to what you'd get with static SQL requires quite a bit more work.

I'd echo Ben's point-- it doesn't appear that you are saving time by structuring your table this way.  You'll likely get much better performance by normalizing the table properly.  I'm not sure what space you believe you are saving but I would tend to doubt that denormalizing your table structure is going to save you much if anything in terms of space.

Comment: I will try this approach for now and consider reviewing my data structure. If I end up normalizing my tables and reformulating my structure I'll let you guys know what my course of action was. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what is required is to create a package with all possible updates (which aren't that many, as I'll only update one field at a given time) and then choosing which query to use depending on my internal logic. This would, however, lead to a big if/else or switch/case-like statement. Is there a way to achieve similar results with better performance?